# Synchronizing access to map in golang: sync.RWMutex vs channels

Tags: go, synchronization, mutex

I'm new to Go, and am trying to understand what is the best way to synchronize concurrent read/write access to a map:  sync.RWMutex vs channels.  It seems like sync.RWMutex is the intuitive way to go, but based on https://pkg.go.dev/sync, this made me second guess myself:

> Other than the Once and WaitGroup types, most are intended for use by low-level library routines. Higher-level synchronization is better done via channels and communication.

Comment: `sync.RWMutex` is perfect for the job. There is no need to complicate simple things with channels. [sync.Map](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Map) is also using mutex.

Comment: this article is related and may be useful: 
https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000040729053/en